# getCurrentPosition deprecated

Tags: iframe, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, deprecation-warning

I've been using Google Maps embedded within a site generated on script.google.com, using the HTML Service as follows:

```
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html');
```

This has been fantastic, I've produced a web app with an embedded map (see https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzFiIPsnNgDnz8pmykbyok1xwDdL85EEAwqohoSo9G1QasbWNk/exec).
However, I am now warned that "getCurrentPosition and watchPosition usage in cross-origin iframes is deprecated and will be disabled in M63, around December 2017".

Trouble is, using HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile on script.google.com gives me no option (that I know of) to append `allow="geolocation"` to the iFrame (the HtmlService generates the iFrame automatically).This will cause the web app to fail in December.

Please advise what I should do to avoid issues!!!

Many thanks,

Sarah.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check these links: [1](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/will-my-weather-api-not-work/154069) and [2: Deprecating Permissions in Cross-Origin Iframes](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes). In order for a cross-origin frame to use these features, the embedding page must specify a Feature Policy which enables the feature for the frame.

For example, to enable geolocation in an iframe, the embedder could specify the iframe tag as:

```
<iframe src="https://example.com" allow="geolocation"></iframe>
```

> If you are a developer of a website which uses cross-origin iframes
>   and you want those iframes to continue to be able to request/use one
>   of the above features, the page that embeds the iframe will need to be
>   changed. The simplest way to do that is to modify the  tag to
>   include an allow attribute which specifies the name of the permission.
>   For example, to enable geolocation and mic/camera for an iframe, the
>   following would be specified:
>
> ```
> <iframe src="https://example.com" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera"></iframe>
> ```
>
> Valid values for allow include:
>
> - geolocation
> - microphone
> - camera
> - midi
> - encrypted-media
>
> Note that if the iframe which is using the permission has the same
>   origin as the top level page, then no changes have to be made.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response Abielita!

That does seem to be on the right track. Unfortunately my issue is that I am not creating the iFrame myself - it is generated automatically by script.google.com.

I would guess I need to instruct the script.google service to somehow incorporate allow="geolocation" into the iFrame when it is generated, but am unsure how this could be done.

I do know that you can use ".setXFrameOptionsMode" to adjust permissions for cross-origin iframes, but this only allows embedding and not geolocation...